# Getting a image to display properly in multiple resolutions

Tags: css

This is the styling, it's in React but I think a CSS solution would be fine.

```
var ontop = {
            position: 'absolute',
            display: 'block',
            height:'auto',
            width: '50%',
            margin: 'auto',
            marginTop: '-50%',
        };
```

Basically If the resolution goes to low it really doesn't work with this styling. It's an image over another image. I'm basically trying to replicate this website http://www.milkbardigital.com.au/ .

This is the html (it's actually jsx but doesn't really matter).

```
            <div style={heroStyle}>
                <Image
                    style={background} responsive
                    src="http://www.milkbardigital.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Milkbar-Home-Background.jpg">
                </Image>
                    <Image
                        style={ontop} responsive
                        src="http://www.milkbardigital.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Milkbar-Digital-Media.png">
                    </Image>
            </div>
```

Appreciate the help. I think it involves using @resolution to fix!

Cheers Mates!

Edit

Here are the other styles

```
var background = {
            backgroundSize : 'cover',
            width: '100%',
        };

var heroStyle = {
            width:'auto',
            overflow : 'hidden',
        };
```

Comment: can you give your 'heroStyle' and 'background' styles also

Comment: _"If the resolution goes to low it really doesn't work"_. Why? What is the problem, specifically?

Comment: Basically the image goes to over other images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TREAT THIS AS A COMMENT I HAVE NO REPUTATION TO COMMENT

Try using bootstrap, it has css classes with media objects, that are fully responsive too every platform and resolution.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't work as the image goes over another - and it's using react-bootstrap